# Android platform and build tools installation Failed to find package 'build-tools;28.03.3'

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-sdk-tools, command-line-tool

I'm trying to use Android Command Line Tools with Ionic without installing Android Studio on Windows 10 OS

In **Environment variables > User variables** *path* C:\Users\User\gradle-6.8.3\bin and *Variable name*: `JAVA_HOME` *Variable value*: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271`, with adding of the same path to **Environment variables > System variables** *path*.

`gradle --version`: Gradle 6.8.3

`java -version`: java version "1.8.0_271"

`node -v`: v14.15.1

`npm -v`: 6.14.8

`ionic -v`: 6.13.1

`cordova -v`: 10.0.0

I've downloaded **commandlinetools-win-6858069_latest.zip** from [android developer](http://%20https://developer.android.com/studio) into previously created folder **Android-SDK** by path C:\Users\User\Android-SDK

In **User variables** of **Environment variables** *Variable name*: ANDROID_HOME *Variable value*: C:\Users\User\Android-SDK, and *path* C:\Users\User\Android-SDK\cmdline-tools

I've created `tools` under `cmdline-tools` folder this way: C:\Users\Asus\Android-SDK\cmdline-tools\tools\bin

Then in Command Prompt I type: `.\Android-SDK\cmdline-tools\tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat "platforms;android-28" "build-tools;28.03.3" "extras;google;m2repository" "extras;android;m2repository"`

```
> Loading package information...               Loading
> local repository...                          [              
> ] 3% Loading local repo[                     ] 3%
> Fetch remote repos[=                         ] 3% Fetch
> remote repos[=                               ] 4% Fetch remote
> repos[=                                      ] 5% Fetch remote
> repos[==                                     ] 5% Fetch remote
> repos[==                                     ] 6% Fetch remote
> repos[==                                     ] 7% Fetch remote
> repos[==                                     ] 8% Fetch remote
> repos[==                                     ] 8% Computing
> updates.[===                                 ] 8% Computing
> updates.[===                                 ] 10% Computing
> updates                                                              
> Warning: Failed to find package 'build-tools;28.03.3' [===            
> ] 10% Computing updates...
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here

Comment: have you found a solution to your problem?

Comment: in linux escaping semicolon `\;` solved my problem